# HLS loadtest with VLC without GUI

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, perl

Im out to test how many connections my HLS stream can handle.

So i think that VLC without GUI can be usefull to do the work.
But the problem is that i'm not manage to start the stream without videocard or soundcard it just giving me this error:

[0x27f4168] inhibit interface error: Failed to connect to the D-Bus session    daemon: /usr/bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally with the following error:    Autolaunch error: X11 initialization failed.

[0x27f4168] main interface error: no suitable interface module
[0x7efdac000b18] main interface error: no suitable interface module
[0x25cf138] main libvlc error: interface "globalhotkeys,none" initialization failed
[0x27f3dc8] dummy interface: using the dummy interface module...
[0x26a6ae8] access_http access error: error: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
[0x26a6ae8] access_http access error: error: HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found
[0x26a6ae8] access_mms access error: error: HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found

```
I using this script :

#!/usr/bin/perl
$i = 0;
$myurl = "http://my-stream/hls/m3u8";
@cmdline = ("/usr/bin/vlc", "");
for( $i = 1; $i <= 100; $i++ )
{
if( $pid = fork )
{
    # parent - ignore
}
elsif( defined $pid )
{
    $cmdline[1] = sprintf "%s:%d", $myurl, $i;
    exec(@cmdline);
}
# elseif - do more error checking here
}
```